# What would be the best questions to ask to assess technical skill on Kubernetes for an interview?

Tags: kubernetes

I have to conduct interviews on a specific position which requires somewhat probing expertise on Kubernetes.

I am not very familiar with it. What would be the best questions that would allow me to assess one's ability on this system ? Those questions can be both technical or generic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of Engineer and questions. Which one do you need? I would ask what's the difference between  pod and replicaset, then between replicaset and deployment, then between deployemnt and statefulset and daemonsets. What Kind of services exist and usecases. Again, you have to know kuberntes, before you ask this questions, or you may make wrong conclusions and decisions. AND AGAIN, it depends on the level of Engineer.